# UWP SDK Version Info

Tags: sdk, uwp, version

I am trying to find version of UWP SDK on my system.j

I am on Windows 10 OS.

Where do I find UWP SDK Version on my Windows 10 system?

Comment: You can go to your packages.config and you will see all the reference packages and their corresponding versions that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called UWP SDK. Maybe it can refer two things

1. **Windows 10 SDK** - You can find all SDK on your computer by going to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsDesktop`
2. **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** NuGet package - You can find the Version on NuGet Package Manager for the particular project.